# Where are "_Jv_RegisterClasses" and "clock_gettime" defined on 32 bit Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

I am try to link some asm code on 32 bit Linux using nasm+gcc

Basically it can not find **clock_gettime** and **_Jv_RegisterClasses**

I tried with

```
gcc -lc test.o
```

and

```
 gcc -lrt final.o
```

but still can not find these two functions..

Could any one tell me where to link these two functions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default linker used by GCC needs to have libraries *after* the object files needing them.

So try instead e.g.

```
$ gcc final.o -lrt
```

Comment: Hi Joachim, great! Thank you! BTW: Do you know where I can link with ** _Jv_RegisterClasses** ..?

Comment: @computereasy There is no standard function in C, POSIX or Linux that's named `RegisterClasses`. Either you're missing an object file when linking, or you have to use some specific library. If it's not in another object file I suggest you turn to your favorite search engine.

Comment: Oh, I think I found out the problem, again , thank you!